# Encoding data to ISO_8859_1 in Bigquery using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have multi language characters in my pyspark dataframe. After writing the data to bigquery it shows me strange characters because of its deafult encoding scheme (utf-8).
How can I change encoding in Bigquery to ISO_8859_1 using pyspark / dataproc?

[image]

Comment: ***"After writing the data to bigquery it shows me strange characters "*** ....... can you show some chracters data example ? where are you openng its content in text editor. it might be possible that text editor you are using might be the issue. give some data examples otherwise its hard time to answer the question

Comment: I am viewing the data in bigquery only. Here is an example of strange characters, that i see: æ±ä¸°æä¿¡å¤§çè¡ç¥¨åè¯å¸æèµåºé

Comment: what is the source of this data taken from is it csv ? I mean csv -> bigquery

Comment: it is a json file that I have parsed in pyspark and encoded the data with ISO_8598_1, while parsing. So transition is like json file --> pyspark dataframe --> bigquery table

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to check at source or source system 
How it's sending the data and understand which encoding it is.   If still different then do the following investigation.

AFAIK pyspark is reading json with utf-8 encoding and loading in to bigquery as per your comments . So its not bigquerys fault as default is utf-8.

you can change encoding to ISO-8859-1 and load json like below

```
spark.read.option('encoding','ISO-8859-1').json("yourjsonpathwith latin-1 ")
```

and load in to bigquery.

Also...

while writing the dataframe in to bigquery.

- you can test/debug using `decode` function with col and charset both in iso-8859-1 and utf-8 formats to understand where its going wrong using...

  `pyspark.sql.functions.decode(columnname , charset)` as well to see its able to decode to utf-8 or not...
- you can write dataframe with `pyspark.sql.functions.decode(col, charset)`

Comment: Hi Ram, I have already done the encoding in pyspark, exactly you mentioned in the answer above. I am not sure whether bigqury will automatically take it as ISO-8859-1 or i have to specify while writing a table to bigquery.

Comment: specify encoding writing in to big query and see

Comment: I am struggling to find how to specify encoding while writing to bigquery. I am using pyspark bigquery connector to write into bigquery

Comment: still not working, it seems to me that, pyspark-bigquery-connector first write data to temporary bucket and then to bigquery, any ideas how to fix now

Comment: have you tried decode function as well ? also this json is not in any compressed format can you check ?

Comment: before saving in to bigquery can you use pyspark.sql.functions.decode(columnname , charset) and prinnt here  try both charset  utf-8, iso-8859-1 lets see

Comment: I did tried decoding in pyspark, it is giving me same results for ISO-85998-1 and UTF-8, it seems not working. In a way, it is pyspark that is not able to recognize the characters.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Please notice that the spark bigquery connector has no "encoding" option, as it takes the Strings from the dataframe's rows

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in the source file itself, as its coming through an api. Hence able to resolve the issue.